# Could anyone explain the meaning of the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

"Systems generally need to fail safe in the open position with local means of disconnecting the power supply to the lock so that escape can be assured even if other circuitry fails to release the door."  It's about the design of electrical locking systems.

Comment: I think you first need to understand the meaning of "fail safe" -- look that up.

Comment: It means, The doors should be guaranteed to be unlocked if power is removed. And that there should be a way for someone inside to remove power.  This probably means that the door locks should be spring-loaded open and that power should be used to hold the lock against the spring.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks "fail safe" did hinder my understanding and I got now. But one more question, what does "in the open position" mean here?

Comment: "fail safe in the open position" means that in the event of a failure (including but not limited to a power failure), the lock will be "safe" (from the standpoint of human safety) because its position will be "open" vs "locked".

Comment: @HotLicks Great! Thanks. It really got me frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Hot Licks, the meaning lies in the word 'fail safe'.

It means: A device which in the event of a specific type of failure, responds in a way that will cause no harm, or at least a minimum of harm, to other devices or to personnel.

Hence, these kind of electrical locking systems need to be fail safe to ensure no harm is done even in the case of a power or even a circuitry failure.